# Arsenal - Rapid Wein. Why wasn't this offside?

Tags: officiating

The following screenshot shows the Maitland-Niles pass to Pepe during the 4-1 Arsenal win over Rapid Wein in the Europa League.

[image]

Arsenal are in blue.

Maitland-Niles is furthest to the the left in blue and is closest to the goal line. He has passed the ball to Pepe second in from the left in blue.

To confirm, Pepe never connected to the ball at any point.

Comment: Who never connected to the ball? Maitland-Niles? Pepe? The goalkeeper?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Pepe never connected with it.

Comment: Which player is which? I'm assuming the Arsenal players are in blue, but is Maitland-Niles or Pepe closer to the goal line? (And please [edit your question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/posts/25389/edit) to include clarifications rather than leaving them in comments - thanks!)

Comment: Philip Kendall, I have made the required edits. Maitland-Niles is indeed the closest to the goal line.

Comment: This is an example of one of the situations given in the duplicate target. Maitland-Niles is in offside position, but as he is not interfering with play or an opponent or gaining an advantage, it is not an offside offence.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Nij. Maitland-Niles is indeed in an offside position but he was onside when he received the ball. What is confusing is that Pepe was offside the moment the ball left Maitland-Niles but Pepe wasn't flagged.

Comment: Pepe is behind the ball, and is not in an offside position. It's not clear from a single image where the ball has moved, and who from, to whom.